# Render Array of objects while joining with a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects such as:

```
const array = [<Button>abc</Button>, <Button>def</Button>]
```

where when I render them with:

```
return array
```

I get a list of buttons next to each other.

something similar to the top line of this example picture:

[image: example]

However I want to join the buttons so it look like the bottom line. I tried to use `array.join("+")` but that no longer rendered buttons instead rendering `<object object>+<object object>`

Is it possible to do this? keep in mind the array needs to be looped to include all items and ideally it knows not to add a `+` to the last element.

Comment: Do you want 2 buttons with a "+" between them? A single button with the button text concatenated with a "+"? No button but just the button text concatenated with a "+"? Can you be a bit more explicit with the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Its a tricky use-case. I was able to achieve writing conditional inside map function.

```
  {array.map((item, index) => {
    if (index === array.length - 1) {
      return item;
    }
    return [item, "+"];
  })}
```

Here's working example link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hceymc

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var btnArray = [], btnString = "";

btns.forEach(curr => {
    btnArray.push(curr);
});

btnArray.forEach(curr =>{
    btnString += curr.innerText + "+";
});

btnString = btnString.substring(0, btnString.length - 1);
console.log(btnString);
```

**A simpler method using join() would look like this**

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var btnArray = [], btnText = [], btnString = "";

btns.forEach(curr => {
    btnArray.push(curr);
});

btnArray.forEach(curr =>{
    btnText.push(curr.innerText);
});

btnString = btnText.join(" + ");
console.log(btnString);
```